# JTreeTable updating

Tags: java, jtable, jtree, updating, jtreetable

I'm trying to use the example taken from the http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable2/index.html, in which I've substituted the filesystem model with my model.

I initially create a model, I display it in the `JTreeTable`, but now I'd like to update my model and then the `JTreeTable` (for example I want to add a node at the tree, modify a node, remove a node, etc.).

I don't know how I can do it. I can't see method that allow me to do what I want, I only see some method like `treeNodesChanged`, `treeNodesInserted`, etc.,  but probably I miss something in the global logic of this `JTreeTable` component.

Besides I'm not sure that I correctly create the model, because in various example I've seen people call various method over a "model" object (`model.insertNodeInto`, `model.reload`), inspite of I haven't a model object..In the example above, is simply called the abstract class `AbstractTreeTableModel` which implements `TreeTableModel`..

**Update**

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel 
                         implements TreeTableModel {
 static protected String[]  cNames = {"TrackNumber", "MWRTN", "LSRTN", "RFTN","TrackStatus","Prova","Prova2"};
    // Types of the columns.
 static protected Class[]  cTypes = {TreeTableModel.class,Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class,String.class,String.class};

 private ArrayList<Object> data=new ArrayList<Object>();
     public void insertNode(Object node)
     {    this.data.add(node);    super.setRoot(data.get(0));}
```

In my main class I add objects to my model in this way:

```
...
model =new TableModel();
model.insertNode(threatList.get(i)); //inserting the root node
model.addChild(threatList.get(i),threatList.get(j)); // inserting the child
...
```

Then I pass the model to my `JTreeTable` and add it to my frame:

```
treeTable = new JTreeTable(model);
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(treeTable);
scroll.setAutoscrolls(false);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,80));
frame.add(scroll);
```

And this is the JTreeTable class:

```
public class JTreeTable extends JTable {
protected TreeTableCellRenderer tree;

public JTreeTable(TreeTableModel treeTableModel) {
super();

// Create the tree. It will be used as a renderer and editor. 
tree = new TreeTableCellRenderer(treeTableModel); 

// Install a tableModel representing the visible rows in the tree. 
super.setModel(new TreeTableModelAdapter(treeTableModel, tree));

// Force the JTable and JTree to share their row selection models. 
tree.setSelectionModel(new DefaultTreeSelectionModel() { 
    // Extend the implementation of the constructor, as if: 
 /* public this() */ {
    setSelectionModel(listSelectionModel); 
    } 
}); 
// Make the tree and table row heights the same. 
tree.setRowHeight(getRowHeight());

// Install the tree editor renderer and editor. 
setDefaultRenderer(TreeTableModel.class, tree); 
setDefaultEditor(TreeTableModel.class, new TreeTableCellEditor());  

setShowGrid(false);
setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0)); 
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,60));
}

/* Workaround for BasicTableUI anomaly. Make sure the UI never tries to 
 * paint the editor. The UI currently uses different techniques to 
 * paint the renderers and editors and overriding setBounds() below 
 * is not the right thing to do for an editor. Returning -1 for the 
 * editing row in this case, ensures the editor is never painted. 
 */
public int getEditingRow() {
    return (getColumnClass(editingColumn) == TreeTableModel.class) ? -1 : editingRow;  
}

// 
// The renderer used to display the tree nodes, a JTree.  
//

public class TreeTableCellRenderer extends JTree implements TableCellRenderer {

protected int visibleRow;

public TreeTableCellRenderer(TreeModel model) { 
    super(model); 
}

public void setBounds(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    super.setBounds(x, 0, w, JTreeTable.this.getHeight());
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.translate(0, -visibleRow * getRowHeight());
    super.paint(g);
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                           Object value,
                           boolean isSelected,
                           boolean hasFocus,
                           int row, int column) {
    if(isSelected)
           setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    else
           setBackground(table.getBackground());

    visibleRow = row;
    return this;
    }
 }

 // 
 // The editor used to interact with tree nodes, a JTree.  
 //

public class TreeTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                             boolean isSelected, int r, int c) {
        return tree;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I would is to fire an event after adding(or modifying, or removing) a child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is the class holding your data. It must tell its view each time the data changes, so that the view refreshes itself and shows the new data of the model. This is the goal of the methods `fireXxx()`.

Like with the other Swing components, when you change the data displayed by the component, you should thus do it by changing the data in the model, and call the appropriate fireXxx methods. The best thing to do is to encapsulate this in the model class, by adding specific methods in your subclass of AbstractTreeTableModel which perform the data modification and fire the appropriate event using one or several calls to `fireXxx`.

I suggest you read the Swing tutorial about [tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and or [trees](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and then apply what you learn here to your tree table. The idea is the same.

Comment: The method fireTreeNodesInserted takes four parameters:

    source - the node where new elements are being inserted
    path - the path to the root node
    childIndices - the indices of the new elements
    children - the new elements

In my case I've to add a children called A1 to a father called A, so after I've added this in my model, I have to call the   fireTreeNodesInserted()...the first and the last parameters I imagine that are A and A1 respectively...but I don't know how fill the second and the third...

Comment: the third should be an array containing a single element: the index (starting at 0) of A1 in the list of A's children. If it's the first child of A, it should thus contain 0. The second argument is the path from the A to the root. It should thus contain A as its first element, then A's parent, etc. until the root node, at the last index. There is a utility method in DefaultTreeModel (getPathToRoot) to do that for you.

Comment: Mmh..ok...but I still don't understand something...  Have I create the array contains the children? About the path...I've seen the method getPathRoot(), but I wouldn't know where to start!